# Is RestTemplate going to be deprecated in coming Spring release?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Currently, I am using Spring Boot Starter **3.1.3**. I need to make calls to some Rest endpoints.

There is RestTemplate which I can use. Also, I have seen there are WebClient (sync and async) and RestClient.

If I go with RestTemplate will that be fine or is there any plan to deprecate the RestTemplate?

Also please suggest which one should I go ahead with.

Answer (score 2):

For new projects, go with the new **RestClient** which is the more modern alternative of `RestTemplate` with additional features and active development.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new service and have a choice between RestTemplate and WebClient - I'd go with WebClient.

According to the [RestTemplate doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html):

> As of 5.0 this class is in maintenance mode, with only minor requests for changes and bugs to be accepted going forward. Please, consider using the org.springframework.web.reactive.client.WebClient which has a more modern API and supports sync, async, and streaming scenarios.

Spring Boot Starter 3.1.3 that you mentioned uses Spring Framework 6.0.6 under the hood, so that doc applies to your case too.

Comment: So RestTemplate is not going to be deprecated, right? And for WebClient, I need to add spring-webflux dependency. But when I add this dependency, it fetches 20 - 22 libraries. Is there any specific library that I can add to get the WebClient? So that I can minimize the no of extra dependency.

Comment: Maybe you can use java rest client. here is the link https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client